# btree_gin index is not used for sorting

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Let's assume I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.widgets
(
  id          bigserial primary key,
  categories  int[] not null
);
```

With a `btree_gin` index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
CREATE INDEX widgets_idx ON test.widgets USING gin (categories, id);
```

I insert some test data:

```
INSERT INTO test.widgets (categories)
(
  SELECT ARRAY[
      (random() * 1000)::int,
      (random() * 1000)::int,
      (random() * 1000)::int,
      (random() * 1000)::int
  ]
  FROM generate_Series(1,100000)
);
```

Then I want to query all the widgets from a given category, but ordered by `id`:

```
SELECT id, categories
FROM test.widgets
WHERE ARRAY[48] <@ widgets.categories
ORDER BY id;
```

Instead of using the `btree_gin` index for sorting, the sorting is done in memory:

```
Sort  (cost=2124.05..2125.45 rows=561 width=40) (actual time=5.107..5.120 rows=402 loops=1)
  Sort Key: id
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 56kB
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on widgets  (cost=1244.35..2098.43 rows=561 width=40) (actual time=4.759..5.061 rows=402 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ('{48}'::integer[] <@ categories)
        Heap Blocks: exact=320
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on widgets_idx  (cost=0.00..1244.21 rows=561 width=0) (actual time=4.700..4.700 rows=402 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ('{48}'::integer[] <@ categories)
Planning time: 0.158 ms
Execution time: 5.171 ms
```

How to make sure the query leverages the index?

Comment: Your index needs a categorie and an id to work properly? Am I wrong?

Comment: It's pretty basic for a btree index to be able to provide sorting.

Comment: @Flavien: They're not "real" `btree`s, though... They're B-trees posing as `gin`. And the very definition of `ORDER BY` is in terms of default `btree` opclasses (see the footnote [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html)). The opclasses in the `btree_gin` extension happen to be based around the same set of operators, but this is true of exactly *none* of the built-in `gin` classes, so it's unlikely that Postgres is equipped to exploit this coincidence. tl;dr: You probably can't :(

Comment: How can you hit 2,233 rows from 10,000, times 4 values each when looking for 1/1,000 proportion of values?

Comment: I edited the query, let me update the query plan.